# Uploading image with Javascript, then having it appear in embedded SWF

Tags: javascript, actionscript, upload, flash

I need to upload an image to a SWF, however I can't use ActionScript for it because the client wants drag-and-drop capability. I figure that I can make the upload button cause a popup, where there is JavaScript for drag-and-drop.  The SWF allows for some photo manipulation, so the image needs to be uploaded, and be in the SWF for that use. My question is, how can I make that image accessible to the SWF file?

Thank You!

Comment: when the drag and drop even is complete use external interface to call an actionscript function that takes the image path as its argument.

Comment: Post that as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: Overall I would tend to agree with zevan's answer, but you may want to clarify for us exactly how you are uploading the image in JavaScript. Do you mean you are using an input form to upload the file to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with mostly with ActionScript plus a little bit of JavaScript.
Redirect all HTML DOM events to Flash via ExternalInterface.

The following example no more work on lastest Firefox or Chrome, due to lack of seting up window mode (wmode = opaque or transparent in our case):
http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/wiki/FFDragAndDroptoFlash

[Understanding HTML5 drag and drop API](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)